# Regex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the special character '?' in every column individually of a data frame df1.
however unable to get a result of  count.
I have tried codes such as

**df1[df1.columns.str.match('?')== True]**

but receive an error: nothing to repeat at position 0

I have also tried df1.columns.str.count('?') again i receive a value error.

Can someone please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Because `?` is special regex character, is necessary escape it:

```
df1.columns.str.count('\?')
```